# Parsing C string and multiple pointer c string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make a parser. I have a version working with just pointers but I want to know how to convert it from pointers (char *p) to c strings (char p[]) to get more familiar with how they work.

I have a function...

```
int makearg(char s[], char**args[])
{
    char *arg1
    char arg2[50];

    //I'm aware these don't assign the args pointer value to arg2.
    arg2[0] = args[0];

    //And I'm aware this does.
    arg1 = (*args)[0]);
}
```

My question is what is the equivalent. Or maybe a brief explanation on what's going on. Other solutions just give working code without really saying how it works.

I don't think this is related by my mem allocation is using the pointer and []. And that works fine. Little unsure how that works also if anyone has time.

```
(*args)[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * tokenLen);
```

Comment: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which compiler error are you asking about? What words, specifically, from those errors have you confused? When you post examples here you need to be certain they produce only the problem you're asking about, and no other problems. You can do this by producing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Invalid conversion from char* to char** or whatever combination I was trying. I knew the types were different but I didn't understand how. Every time I compiled it would give me an error and then I would adjust to get the error to go away but the pointer would be wrong. So I think I get it now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first statement:**

```
arg2[0] = args[0];
```

`arg2[0]` is of type `char` and `args[0]` is of type `char**`. This assignment wont work because they are of different types.

However, something like this would work:

```
arg2[0] = (**args)[0]; /* or even (*args)[0][0] */
```

because you are giving `arg2[0]` a `char`, which is correct because they are matching types. `**args` is a pointer to a pointer to the first element of `args`, which is `char*`, and to reach a `char`, you need to index `[0]`. Their are multiple ways you could do this. Assigning `arg2[0]` to `args[0][0][0]` or even `***args` is valid, even though these assignments would look obscure.

**The second statement:**

```
arg1 = (*args)[0];
```

will work because you are giving `arg1`, a `char*` pointer.`*args` is a pointer to first element of of `args`, which is `char**`, and index`[0]` locates to a `char*` pointer. This stores the address of `(*args)[0];` within `arg1`. This could even be written in a much less popular way `&(*(*args)[0])`, although this is harder to read and not necessary.

Additionally, Your memory allocation is fine. `(*args)[i]` is a pointer to the first element of args, which is `char**`, and `[i]` would reference a `char*` pointer. You would need to allocate for `char**` before hand, as this is also an uninitialized pointer to pointer.

You can also shorten:

```
(*args)[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * tokenLen);
```

to:

```
(*args)[i] = malloc(tokenLen);
```

As you [don't need to cast return of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. 
'

Comment: You are a saint. Thank you heavenly spirit. <3

Comment: @cba1067950 No problem :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

`char[]` and `char *` is effectively the same thing because the compiler converts arrays to pointers. So there is no need to convert between them.

Think of the array syntax as a shortened version of a pointer dereference with an offset: `arg[5] == *(arg + 5)`

---

`arg2[0] = args[0];` is not going to compile because args[0] is `char**` and arg2[0] is of type `char`.

`arg1 = (*args)[0]);` works because you they both have the same type - `char *`.